# Espresso wrong query (or test's cache)

Tags: android, android-espresso

I try to make a following test

```
@Test
public void testItShowsErrorOnEmptyLogin() {
    onView(withId(R.id.bluebutton_button)).perform(click());
    onView(withId(R.id.bluebutton_button)).check(matches(withText("Укажите логин и пароль")));
}
```

But it fails with error

```
android.support.test.espresso.NoMatchingViewException: No views in hierarchy found matching: (with id: com.app:id/bordered_text_view and with text: is "Войти" and Child at position 0 in parent Child at position 0 in parent with id: 2131296288 and is displayed on the screen to the user)
```

I dont understand, why in error it complains to query which I dont use in test. Looks like cache from previous test or something like that.

How to fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

It can be due to cache.
So, just try to clear the cache of Android Studio.
You can do it by **File->Invalidate Cache/Restart** on Android Studio.

Thanks